# Threejs rotate an object around another object in 3d matrix axis

Tags: javascript, random, three.js, rotation, axis

Right now I could able to set one axis to rotate.

```
Working code: 
https://codepen.io/itzkinnu/full/erwKzY
```

How to rotate an object in random axis instead of one fixed axis.

Something like this
[image: Random rotation]

Comment: I included your picture in the question, though I have no idea how it is supposed to help us. Please include your code in the question too. If you want answers, you have to help people answer for you.

Comment: Look here to rotate around a user defined axis: [.rotateOnAxis](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D.rotateOnAxis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an object to positioned relative to an other object, then the object has to be added as a child of the reference object.

Use [`Object3D.add`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.add) to add a child to an object.

See the example:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, loader, camera, scene, renderer, controls, mesh, child;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, -4, -1.5);

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.x = -0.75;
    directionalLight.position.y = -0.5;
    directionalLight.position.z = -1;
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(2);
    scene.add(axis);
    
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#f08080'});
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#8080f0'});
    var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    child = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);
    child.position.x = 1.5;

    mesh.add(child);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  function resize() {
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
  
    child.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    child.rotateY(0.02)
    child.translateX(1.5);

    mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    mesh.rotateZ(0.01);
    mesh.translateX(1.0);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rabbid76 for the quick response. It actually helped.

I have added

child.rotateY(0.02);

to the above code in animate function to rotate in random axis.

May I know how to make child box self rotate?

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, loader, camera, scene, renderer, controls, mesh, child;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, -4, -1.5);

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.x = -0.75;
    directionalLight.position.y = -0.5;
    directionalLight.position.z = -1;
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(2);
    scene.add(axis);
    
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#f08080'});
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#8080f0'});
    var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    child = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);
    child.position.x = 1.5;

    mesh.add(child);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  function resize() {
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
  
    child.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    child.rotateY(0.02)
    child.translateX(1.5);

    mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    mesh.rotateZ(0.01);
    mesh.translateX(1.0);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```